# trigger an browser alert when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, onclick

im trying to let the user know that he submitted his form by a simple alert, but somehow this leads to not working. To do this I bound a onClick function to the type="submit" field.

here are my code snippets

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <input onclick="formSuc" type="submit" class="btn btn-box" value="ABSENDEN">
 </div>

 <script>
    function formSuc() {
        alert("Test");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your onclick property to this:

```
onclick="formSuc()"
```

This way, your function will execute *onclick*.